# android put button at edge of view

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, floating-action-button

[image: Example view]

I'm trying to add a `floating action button` on the corner of an `image view` as such. I have looked over all the current solutions on stackoverflow, but the answers I came across were not detailed and only contained broad information like "use layout anchor" or "use frame layout". How would I go about doing this? By the way, the root layout I am using is a `constraint layout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you are using constraint layout so you can set the button to the bottom right of that grey background view.

In the XML for your view, make sure the button comes after your grey view in the XML file and set the button's constraint layout attributes (I've given arbitrary values for layout_width and layout_height:

```
...

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/backrgoundGreyView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/headerMenuButton"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/backgroundGreyView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/backgroundGreyView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/backgroundGreyView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/backgroundGreyView"/>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attributes:
`layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` but it works only inside `CoordinatorLayout`

Sample:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It will looks like:

[image]

Comment: How would I make the same effect when using `wrap content` for the `coordinator layout` attributes? Currently, using `wrap content` makes the button go inside the `imagview`. I want to keep my base layout as a `constraint layout` and nest a `coordinator layout` only for this `imageview` and `button`.

Comment: As a workaround you can add `margin` attribute to `ImageView`:  

`<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Output:
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjyt6.png)

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#255177">

<!--Image code-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_box"
        android:src="@drawable/demo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/edit_pro" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both in a `ConstraintLayout` and manipulate the constraints to the fab top & bottom.

But this isn't enough to have the button engaged in the image, so, you can add handle this by scaling the FAB and/or image with `android:scaleX` & `android:scaleY` and set the FAB size to be mini with `app:fabSize="mini"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0E153A">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_frame"
        android:scaleX="1.1"
        android:scaleY="1.1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#3D5AF1"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/msimageg"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24"
        app:tint="#FFF" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]